# Laravel Passport keep track of the state value

Tags: laravel, alexa-skills-kit, laravel-passport

Does passport keep track of the state value it is being passed when it is trying to authorize a user to the client.

In the Alexa documentation it says:
    It must keep track of the state value passed in the query string.
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html#h3_login_req

If it doesn't does anyone now how to change passport so it will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Passport handles state by default. It has a `->stateless()` method when it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have figure out why it still don't work.